# keepalive set paho.mqtt simple API automatic disconnect

Tags: python-3.x, synchronization, mqtt, paho

I want to code a synchronous programs in which cloud send mqtt message to device, then using simple to wait response to judge whether is successed. but it need a timeout, such as 5 seconds, app think it's failed. The keepalive parameter of mqtt simple API seems to lose efficacy, but the big probability is that I use or understand the error.

I would very appreciate it if you guys can suggest me some advice

```
print("----before simple")
    msg = subscribe.simple("paho/test/simple", hostname="39.100.79.76",port=1883,keepalive=5,will = {'topic': "paho/test/disconnect", 'payload':"network or device anomaly", 'qos':2, 'retain':0})
    print("----after simple")
```

then run it, simple API cannot to end

```
----before simple
infinite...
```

Correctly determine if it is successful to synchronize the edge cloud application

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem so that it is easier to help

Answer (score 1):

You have miss understood what the `keepalive` property for a MQTT client is for.

The `keepalive` is used by the Broker to check if the client is still functioning. It does this by keeping a timer since the last MQTT packet was received from the client. If it does not receive a packet when the timer reaches the `keepalive` time it sends a MQTT Ping request to the client. If it doesn't receive a response to that packet with in half the `keepalive` time then is will disconnect the client and publish any Last Will & Testament message that the client may have set.

The Paho client library handles MQTT Ping messages in the background with  no need for the user to be involved.

The code sample you have provided will wait indefinitely for a response.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. The second, please give me some advice to use MQTT for application operation synchronization, such as cloud sending operation information to the device for control, to determine whether it is successful, If the network is abnormal or the device fails, the cloud can know the operation fails. Thank you very much.

Comment: Those are unrelated to the original question you asked, you can ask a new question and reference this one of needed